# how to view user posts friends - Firestore

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

How could I view the posts, only from friends?

in this example I would like to display in RecyclerView only the posts of my friends. In this case the user 15. (certainly is several friends, I put only one to exemplify)

Structure - database:

```
USERS
-user01 (current user)
-name: John
-age: 20
--friends
----user10
----user15

-POSTS
--idpost_98685754
---user_post: user15
---title_post: Title
---photo: link

-posts
--idpost_41254d4554s1
---user_post: user40
---title_post: Title
---photo: link

-posts
--idpost_121221sss1
---user_post: user15
---title_post: Title 2
---photo: link 2

-posts
--idpost_9865565555
---user_post: user15
---title_post: Title 3
---photo: link 3
```

I currently use only the simple order and limit functions explained in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data). This is the first time I need to do something like that.

**EDIT:**

CODE - FRAGMENT:

```
/*Firebase*/
mDb = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
mQuery = mDb.collection("Posts");
Query mQueryNew = mQuery.orderBy("timestamp", Query.Direction.DESCENDING);



/* Recycler */
mCardFeedList = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(id.cardFeedUser_list);
mCardFeedList.setHasFixedSize(true);
mCardFeedList.setItemViewCacheSize(20);
mCardFeedList.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);


mAdapter = new PostsAdapter(mQueryNew, this){

    @Override
    protected void onDataChanged() {

        if (getItemCount() == 0) {
            mCardFeedList.setVisibility(View.GONE);


        } else {
            mCardFeedList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }


    }
};

llmanager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
mCardFeedList.setLayoutManager(llmanager);
mCardFeedList.setAdapter(mAdapter);


/*START*/
if (mAdapter != null) {
    mAdapter.startListening();

}
```

ADAPTER:

```
public class PostsAdapter extends FirestoreAdapter<PostsAdapter.ViewHolder> {


    public interface OnPostsListner{

        void onPostSelected(DocumentSnapshot post);
        void onLikeSelected(DocumentSnapshot like);
        void onCurtidasSelected(DocumentSnapshot curtidas);
        void onFotoSelected(DocumentSnapshot foto);
        void onCommentsSelected(DocumentSnapshot coments);


    }


    private OnPostsListner mListner;
    public PostsAdapter (Query query, OnPostsListner listner){

        super(query);
        mListner = listner;

    }


    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        return new ViewHolder(inflater.inflate(R.layout.card_feed_user_row, parent, false));

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.bind(getSnapshot(position), mListner);
    }


    static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private Boolean mIsliked = false;

        @BindView(R.id.tvCardFeedUser_nome)
        TextView nomeUser;

        @BindView(R.id.tvCardFeedUser_horario)
        TextView horaFeed;

        @BindView(R.id.tvCardFeedUser_desc)
        TextView descFeed;

        @BindView(R.id.ivCardFeedUser_image)
        ImageView imageFeed;

        @BindView(R.id.secaoLike)
        LinearLayout curtir;

        @BindView(R.id.secaoComments)
        LinearLayout comentarios;

        @BindView(R.id.tv_card_feed_linear_curtidas)
        LinearLayout linear_curtidas;

        @BindView(R.id.idBtnLike)
        TextView btnLike;

        @BindView(R.id.tv_card_feed_numero_curtidas)
        TextView curtidas;

        @BindView(R.id.tv_card_feed_nome_curtida)
        TextView nome_curtidas;



        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);


        }


        public void bind(final DocumentSnapshot snapshot,
                         final OnPostsListner listener) {

            final Posts ref = snapshot.toObject(Posts.class);
            FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
            FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
            final FirebaseUser mCurrentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();


            nomeUser.setText(ref.getNome_user());
            descFeed.setText(ref.getDesc());
            //Foto
            Picasso.with(itemView.getContext()).load(ref.getImage()).placeholder(R.drawable.bck_padrao).networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE).into(imageFeed, new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError() {

                    Picasso.with(itemView.getContext()).load(ref.getImage()).placeholder(R.drawable.bck_padrao).into(imageFeed);

                }
            });

            SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/M/yy HH:mm");
            String novaData = formatter.format(ref.getTimestamp());
            horaFeed.setText(novaData);

            /*CLICKS*/
            curtir.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    if (listener != null) {
                        listener.onLikeSelected(snapshot);

                    }

                }
            });

            imageFeed.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    if (listener != null) {
                        listener.onFotoSelected(snapshot);

                    }

                }
            });

            comentarios.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    if (listener != null) {
                        listener.onCommentsSelected(snapshot);
                    }

                }
            });

            linear_curtidas.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {


                    if (listener != null) {
                        listener.onCurtidasSelected(snapshot);

                    }
                }
            });

            // Click listener
            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if (listener != null) {
                        listener.onPostSelected(snapshot);
                    }
                }
            });

        }


    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve this, you need to query your database twice using nested query. First of all you need to query the database to get all the friends id that correspond to a single user and then based on those ids to query the database for the second time to display only the post de correspond to those particular friends.

One thing to note is that this cannot be done in a single query.

Comment: Would you help me? I can even query and retrieve friends, but I can not save that result and run them in another query. @AlexMamo

Comment: please check my update on the above question. @AlexMamo

Comment: To solve this, there is no need to share RecyclerView, just only the lines where you query. But to solve this, please see my answer from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47308356/how-can-i-give-access-to-certain-objects-in-firebase-database-based-on-id). It's almost the same, but is for for Firebase. The main idea is the same.

Comment: Yes, I checked. But I did not quite understand. How do I get the ID result and transform it into a Query compatible with the Firestore. Because the adapter waits for a Query. Link to answer (http://prntscr.com/hne18k). @AlexMamo

Comment: That was a simple example on how things are working in Firebase. I adviced you to adapt that code to Firestore. The main idea is the same. When it comes to Firestore we don't use `DatabaseReference` or `Query`, we use **`DocumentReference`**. This what you need to use.

Comment: in summary, I'll have to read the database and capture the friend's user codes. Then go through the database again, and create a list with the posts found? @AlexMamo

Comment: to finish In the created list, is it recommended to capture only the ID/key or all the post data? @AlexMamo

Comment: Only the id and based on that id, you can query the second time.

Comment: @AlexMamo yes this is the right procedure. Lets say i have 10 friends, would the query be done ten times with the ids to get all the posts of those users? or is there subquerying in firestore?

Comment: In the conditions explained by the OP, yes, you'll query ten times. If you have other particular questions, please post another fresh question, so me and other users can help you.